# paper.js - PointText font not set until drag

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs

Using paper.js, I'm creating one-character-long text objects the screen using the following call:

```
var text = new paper.PointText({
  point: [x,y],
    content: "9",
    fillColor: "white",
    font: "Comfortaa",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 30
});
```

I'm however encountering the issue where the text is rasterized onto the screen with whatever default font is defined on the body and it stays that way until I move the PointText object with a tool's drag event. As soon as I move the piece of text with the mouse, the text immediately changes font to, in this case, Comfortaa. Here are two screenshots of before and after:

[image: before drag, font is the default Open Sans]
[image: after dragging the character to the left, fonts change]

It doesn't look like calling paper's draw() after the first draw makes much of a difference here. Also, the fonts are not loaded asynchronously with something like Google Fonts API, they're local and thus that's not the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Using Jürg Lehni's suggestion, I was able to make it work by adding a new div, setting the visibility to hidden, and the font family to my webfont.

`<div style="visibility: hidden; font-family: 'Share Tech Mono';">test</div>`